# Is the Android Emulator from Android Studio vulnerable to Dirty COW?

Tags: rooting, security, linux, vulnerability

I want to try out the DirtyCOW Exploit in a Virtual Machine or an Emulator. I have made DirtyCOW run on some versions of Android-x86, with Android-x86 running in VirtualBox.

I want to know if DirtyCOW works in the Android Emulator aswell. Does the emulator emulate the linux kernel, or are the syscalls implemented by the emulator?

Comment: Emulators emulate a full system including kernel in difference to simulators.

Comment: @Robert That is what I needed to know, thank you!